# Javascript how to append an element to div with specific class

Tags: javascript

I have some `<div>`s where I want to append some data to a child div with a specific class but I'm not sure how to do that:

Here is my JS code:

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
items.forEach(function (item) {

  let textnode = document.createElement('p');
  textnode.innerHTML = 'some text';
  item.appendChild(textnode);
});
```

This actually works, bu it only appends the "textnode"-element to the existing elements.

When I try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('left').appendChild(textnode);
```

It doesn't work.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avurbh1s/9/)

**EDIT**

I want to append the data to the `.left` element

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` Notice the `s` at `elements`. You are getting a list (a `NodeList` to be exact). Loop over the elements inside

Comment: "it only appends the "textnode"-element to the existing elements" — Well, yes. That's what I would expect. What did you want? To have something which monitored the DOM to look for new elements which are members of that class and then add the paragraph when they appeared?

Comment: Re edit: *I want to append the data to the .left element* — So do it the same way as you do in the working code!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to append an element to `.left` descendant of `item` elements. If this is the case, you can use the `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName`:

```
item.querySelector('.left').appendChild(textnode);
```

Note that above code calls the `querySelector` method as a member of `item` (instance of [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement) interface).

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements. Class names are not unique. Therefore you first need to select an element in that list.

```js
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Test");
var node = document.getElementsByClassName('left');
node[0].appendChild(textnode);
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
```

Comment: This is a FAQ, so if this is the answer it should be closed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) not given another version of this answer.

Comment: Node lists are not arrays.

Comment: @Quentin True my bad.

Answer (score -1):

getElementsByClassName returns the array of elements. So u need to use the index for that.

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName('left')
x[0].appendChild(textnode)
```

This is working.
I have updated the code in your fiddle. Please check out

Comment: "the arrays of elements" — Node lists are not arrays.

Comment: And this is a FAQ, so if this is the answer it should be closed as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) not given another version of this answer.

Comment: getElementsByClassName is pure JS method returns an array of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object.

Comment: It is DOM, not "pure JS" (you won't find it in  the ECMAScript spec) and it does not return an array. It returns a Node List. Node Lists are not arrays.